# ¿Qué significa el @ en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Me he encontrado el siguiente código donde algunas palabras clave van precedidas por la arroba (@). ¿Qué es eso? ¿Por qué se ponen un `@` antes de `var`?

```
class LinkedList {

  @param {Function} [comparatorFunction]
  constructor(comparatorFunction) { @var LinkedListNode this.head = null;

  @var LinkedListNode
  this.tail = null;

  this.compare = new Comparator(comparatorFunction);
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco seguramente tienes interacción con un html helper

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, porfavor revisa el [tour] y de paso lee [ask], te faltan etiquetas en la pregunta, no creo que eso sea javascript puro.

Comment: Encontre esto en stackoverflow en ingles, esto responde a tu pregunta?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759485/what-do-private-public-class-and-param-mean-in-js

Comment: si   exacto ya lo comprendí  , gracias por el  aporte

Comment: @Riven o andy andrade deberías poner eso como respuesta para que sirva de ayuda a otros usuarios que puedan tener la misma duda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Segun el siguiente enlace encontrado en stackoverflow en inglés:

[what do @private, @public, @class and @param mean in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759485/what-do-private-public-class-and-param-mean-in-js)

Se nos explica que estos parametros que usan el caracter `@` enrealidad no es código que lee javascript, si no que hace parte del formato de documentación que usan los editores de codigo, por ejemplo en visual studio code, cuando nosotros ponemos el cursor encima de alguna función originaria de javascript, podemos ver ciertos datos descritos de manera especial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi que enrealidad esto no es código ejecutable de javascript ni un nuevo paradigma ni algo nuevo de javascript, esto simplemente hace parte de la documentación, donde para poder definir documentacion deberemos usar la siguiente notación:

```
/**Aqui la descripcion de la documentacion...*/
function js(){

}
```

Nótese que al inicio deben ir dos asteriscos juntos en vez de uno solo (**), puesto que si no, no estaríamos definiendo documentación, si no simples comentarios, comentarios que no se veran en el infoarea de `VSCode`.

El resultado de esto:

```
/**Aqui la descripcion de la documentacion...*/
function js(){

}
```

Es que si pones el cursor encima de nuestra nueva función por un rato, visual studio code te mostrara la descripción o documentación que pusiste en una pequeña ventana.

Y puedes usar los decoradores `@` junto con ciertas palabras reservadas para "decorar" tu documentación.

Esto es aplicable también a los `IDE` de java solo que ellos usan sus propios decoradores, así que en `eclipse` o en `netbeans` tambien puedes tener este tipo de documentación personalizada haciendo uso del formato `/** */`.

También adjunto los siguientes enlaces o recursos para una mayor comprensión del tema:

[Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

[proposal-decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators)

Comment: Excelente respuesta +1. Tal vez quieras agregar el [código original](https://gist.github.com/twhite96/ae43346b75bfb3f092bf74376c661933) para que quede más claro, porque el AP quitó las marcas de comentarios.

Comment: Gracias, que es el AP??, por supuesto lo tendré en cuenta, pero ese código original que dices, es el que contenía la pregunta del usuario originalmente solamente que el quito las marcas de comentarios??, si es así entonces entiendo que debo hacer.

Comment: AP = Autor de la Pregunta, el equivalente a OP (Original Poster) del sitio en inglés.

Comment: Respecto a tu segunda pregunta, creo que no es necesario, en la respuesta dejaste bastante claro que la documentación tiene formato de comentarios definido.